# Unable to create a Cloud Foundry service in IBM - an IAM service is created instead

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to create a new Watson Conversation service in the Sydney region.

I am trying to do this from this page: https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/watson-assistant-formerly-conversation

When I choose "US South" as the region, the page shows two additional dropdowns: "Choose an organization:" and "Choose a space:". In that case the service is created normally. However, if I select "Sydney" as the region, those two dropdowns disappear.

[image]

As a result, when I create a new Watson Conversation service in Sydney, it is created as an "IAM service" instead of a "Cloud Foundry service". This means the API has a completely different authentication system so it is not suitable for my application.

How do I create a "Cloud Foundry service" in the Sydney region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not work because [Watson Assistant is transitioning towards the IAM model in all regions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/services-information.html#regions). This is also the case for more and more of the other services. It enhances security, gives more control and aligns with the resource model across IBM Cloud. Here is the [relevant part in the Watson Assistant release notes](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/release-notes.html#release-notes).

My recommendation is to look into that IAM (Identity and Access Management) model and adapt it for the app.